# How to add and delete value from enum in class student

Tags: c++, enums

How to add , delete value from enum in c++?
example: 
        If i have class student :

```
 class Student {
string Name;
string fathername;
string sername;
unsigned int    id-std;
unsigned int    old;
```

---

```
int faculty = 0;
 enum { prog , econ , sport };

  add fac(  );

  delete fac (  );
```

Comment: You can not delete enum values

Comment: You simply can't. But better explain the problem you are actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

`enum` in C++ is a set of **named integer constants**, it is evaluated at *compile time* and you can't add or remove values from them like that.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/spelt-and-spelled hehehe :-D

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to use bitmasks, each enum value must be a power of 2, and unique within the enum:

```
enum MyEnum { prog = 1, econ = 2, sport = 4 };
```

To select both `prog` and `econ`, you type:

```
MyEnum v = prog | econ;
```

To later remove the flag `prog`, you type:

```
v = v & ~prog;
```

You can find out more at [the page for bitmasks on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29).

Comment: how i can use that in add fac()

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'add fac()'?

Comment: @Rayan That's probably the best answer for what is (seemingly) your intend. To 'Add' means or-ing the enum value, to 'Remove' means bitwise and operation with the complement of the enum value. C'm on get on to the basics!!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with enum's.

A way could be a map:

```
std::map<std::string, int> theFaculties;
theFaculties["prog"] = 1;
theFaculties["econ"] = 2;
...

int faculty = theFaculties["prog"];
```

You can add/delete but you have to take care of the operator[] because of creating non-existent key's.

Answer (score 0):

An enum is a user-defined type consisting of a set of named **constants** called enumerators. The alternative of using enum is to use `#define` or `const`. So, you can't delete or add values from enum.